# TemplateDoesNotExist at /welcome_page/

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, django, forms

I'm new in coding field. I decided to start a project with Django & Python, but I got stuck due to some errors. For the past 3 weeks, I tried to figure out what was the issue but couldn't find it. I will appreciate it if anyone help.

when I run my code, I get as an error, "TemplateDoesNotExist at /welcome_page/"
Everything as been specified but I'm still getting the same error

Here is the error page:
[TemplateDoesNotExist at /welcome_page/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZOIE.jpg)

content of the welcome page:
[Content of my the welcome page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNZms.jpg)

my URLs :
[URLS where I defined welcome page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laVG9.jpg)

My base content:
[My base content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StDv4.jpg)

the place where the welcome page is calling from:
[The place where the welcome page is calling from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDZ9m.jpg)

My root to the welcome page from my C: drive:
[My root to the welcome page from my C: drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwkC5.jpg)

Comment: I recommend that you include a copy of (or link to) your settings.py file

Comment: @Martin CR, you can find the link of my project on GitHub here :
https://github.com/leosaturnin/InventoryManagement.git

Answer (score 0):

If I see it right, you redirect to /templates/xxx.html but that path is not defined in your paths. The templates directory is the internal location, but the user can only see what is defined in the paths.
You should also better redirect ti the name of the page defined in the paths. Please post your settings.py maybe there is also a problem with the search path for templates.

Comment: this is the link to my project on GitHub, you can have a look.
https://github.com/leosaturnin/InventoryManagement.git

Comment: In the urls.py just put like this: 

   ... welcome_page.as_view(template_name = "welcome_page.html"), name="welcomepage"),

Comment: It's still the same @Razenstein

Answer (score 0):

In your `logout_request()` view the last line is this:

```py
return redirect("templates/welcomepage.html")
```

That's trying to redirect the user to a *template*. It should be redirecting to a *URL*.

In your `urls.py` the Welcome Page view has `name="welcomepage"` - this is what you use to refer to that URL. So change that line in your view to:

```py
return redirect("welcomepage")
```

That will return the user to the "welcomepage" URL, which uses the `views.welcome_page` view, and the `templates/welcome_page.html` template.

---

By the way, if your `welcome_page` view is a class, as opposed to a function (I can't see it in your screenshot, so can't tell) then it's more normal in python to capitalise it: `WelcomePage`. Or `WelcomePageView`. Functions are lowercase (`welcome_page`).

Comment: I checked it but I'm still getting an error.
Here is the link to my project on GitHub. Yu can have a look.
https://github.com/leosaturnin/InventoryManagement.git